# how can I set the position of the element?

Tags: jquery

Here is the jquery

```
$('.li4').click(function(){
    alert($('.img4').offset());
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NPeT/2/)

> but it's alerting object when clicked to `.li4`

Comment: look at `.offset().top` or `.offset().left`

Comment: Use `console.log()` for dubugging.

Comment: Use the console. Never use alert.

Comment: It's alerting 'object' because .offset() method returns an object. What did you expect? BTW, your title supposed you want to set offset() properties, not retrieving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset().left`

```
alert($('.img4').offset().left);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NPeT/3/)

Answer (score 1):

`.offset()` returns an object (`{left,top}`). if you want to view it you can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($('.img4').offset()); // {"top":9,"left":171}
```

Otherwise access the `.left` and `.top` properties:

```
var o = $('.img4').offset();
alert('x: ' o.left + '\ny: ' + o.top);
```